# How to get response's body with mocha / node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm very new to mocha / omf. I have the basic test below:

```
omf('http://localhost:7000', function(client) {
  client.get('/apps', function(response){
    response.has.statusCode(200);
    response.has.body('["test1","test2"]');
  });
});
```

I'd like to check if the value "test2" is among the list returned but I cannot figure out how this is feasible. I'm thinking of something like:

```
omf('http://localhost:7000', function(client) {
  client.get('/apps', function(response){
    response.has.statusCode(200);
    // response.body.split.contains("test2"); // Something like that
  });
});
```

Can I access response.body and then parse the string ?

** UPDATE **

I've tried to test with mocha, just a simple status code:

```
request = require("request");

describe('Applications API', function(){
  it('Checks existence of test application', function(done){
    request
      .get('http://localhost:7000/apps')
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

but I got the following error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'expect'

Any idea ? Does mocha need to have additional addons ?

Comment: have you considered using supertest? That works quite well.

Comment: Sounds cool. It seems to be able to match against a parsed body object... Do you have any examples ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second example can not work as shown.  request.get is asynchronous.

Here's a working example running with request and should

```
request = require("request");
should = require("should");

describe('Applications API', function() {
  it('Checks existence of test application', function(done) {
    request.get('http://google.com', function(err, response, body) {
      response.statusCode.should.equal(200);
      body.should.include("I'm Feeling Lucky");
      done();
    })
  });
});
```